# symfony doctrine multiple relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys, mapping

I'm quite new to Symfony and Doctrine so....

In my application i have the following entities:

```
class Company

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Account", mappedBy="company")
 */
protected $name;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

UserClass (FOSUserBundle):

```
class User extends BaseUser

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $company;
```

and Accounts:

```
class Account

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="num", type="integer")
 */
private $num;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $company;
```

There are the following relations.

one company --> many users, many users --> one company;
one company --> many accounts; many accounts --> one company;

is it possible to generate the relations as i did by:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Account", mappedBy="company")
```

--> two target entities?

thx for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely wrong. If you don't want any links from company to users and accounts then you can just omit this fields. And this relation will be unidirectional. You will have link to Company from both User and Account.

Just omit wrong mappings:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;
```

If you want to create link to users and accounts related to company you need to define fields for these ArrayCollections like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
 */
protected $users;
```

Comment: thx for your quick response! so am i correct that i shoud define fields for every entity i want to relate? (users, and accounts?) and for each entity a new arrayCollection?

Comment: Yep. But if you don't need this ArrayCollections you can omit these fields but the relation in database will exist.

Comment: Thank you! helped me out a lot... now i only have to find out about the ArrayCollections and im good to go on ;-)